# Are there any DIY remedies for a iPhone 4 home button that doesn't always register?

Tags: ios, iphone

The home button on my iPhone seems to work on and off.

It does take me back to the home screen but it feels like there is a loose connection and does not trigger on every press.

Is there a fix to this besides Apple support?

Comment: I have the same issue. The home button works now and then, and sometimes triggers a double click when I only meant to press it once.

Comment: This is a very common problem, and usually can be repaired while you wait at a repair service.

Comment: My wife caught this issue while her phone was still under AppleCare and they swapped it out for a new one. I can't attest to this being standard policy. I'm just providing it as a data point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take it apart and fix it yourself, however it will void any warranty on the phone. You can view the [iFixIt Repair Guide](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Installing-iPhone-4-Home-Button/3144/1) for steps for removing and replacing the Home button. Note that you will have to take apart the majority of the phone to get to the button.

Your best bet would be to go to Apple for a repair or find an authorized repair service shop to do it for you.

Comment: Provided it's not a software-side issue. Also depends if he's still under Applecare, in which case he should go and ask a Genius at the Apple Store...

Comment: @Kheldar, this is a very common hardware problem.

Comment: FWIW, I got the same problem and the Genius asked me if I want a new one, paying $200. I was out of warranty. He said if I didn't want to spend that much I could either fix it myself or bring it to one of those Chinese repair shops. He also told me he shouldn't have told me that.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks guys!

Btw my phone is out of the warranty period, so no luck there.

Here is something I found in the forum that can help as well (not as much as a fix than a workaround) - **AssistiveTouch**, which is baked into iOS. It provides an overlay on the screen for several functions, including the Home button. Credit goes to [Bentsai's answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/34535/22306).

Works great!

Comment: +1, good find! Updated your answer to include some information from the Apple.SE answer you quoted.

Comment: Same problem here. Got the AssistiveTouch tip from a friendly Apple Store employee. Great if your Home Button is really dead; I disabled it after a couple of days as I could not bear the additional button element on the screen anymore.

Answer (score 3):

There is a trick I've used many times to 'fix' my home button, it only takes a couple of seconds and it works every time.  [But, disclaimer, the issues you have may be something different.]

The solution is to insert a charging cable into your iPhone (it doesn't need to connected at the other end, just the bit that goes into the iPhone).  Then if you put your finger on the botton of the connector (the solid bit that goes into the iPhone) and pull it towards you.

It would appear that the hardware parts are somehow separating inside the iPhone through repeating use of dock stations / connectors, and this just helps to squeeze the parts back together - albeit it isn't as good as it worked on day 1.

Answer (score 2):

This is commonly caused by a build up of dirt and or grease under the button, thus interfering with the contacts. One resolution is to get some 70%+ alcohol wipes and squeeze some of the liquid into the gap around the button (with the phone off) and give it a good old pressing. Leave it to dry for a few minutes and test. You don't want to go crazy with the amount you put in, but this will sort it out in many cases.

Comment: This is perfect! I used WD-40 though, and everything works fine now!

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same issue. I'm convinced it's a software issue, due to reboot "fixing" it for a while, which might help you also.

Answer (score 0):

The alcohol wipes thing did the trick .. Just put some of the liquid from it on your home button so that it can go inside .. Switch off phone and press the home button many times so that the liquid somewhat goes inside . Wipe it off and check it .. Works like a pro

Answer (score 0):

The guy at the Apple Store told me to press the homebutton rapidly (center and moren on the sides). You will see the dirt come out. Wipe it off and repeat it until there is no more dirt coming out. Works fine for me.