# Could software cause the iPhone's home button to become unresponsive?

Tags: itunes, ios, applications, iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flaky iPhone 4 Home Button](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8620/flaky-iphone-4-home-button)

I've got an iPhone 4, and for a while now the home button has been quite unresponsive.  Sometimes I need to press the button around 5 or 6 times for it to register.  However, I noticed that once I restore it to factory settings, the home button goes back to normal.

Once I put my apps and music on the iphone once again, the home button problem reappears.  Has anyone heard of a problem like this, or is it just a coincidence? What can be done to fix it? Should I reinstall iTunes and re-download all my apps?

Comment: Have you looked at the many questions on this site discussing the same problem? http://apple.stackexchange.com/search?q=%2Biphone+%2Bhome+%2Bbutton

Answer (score -1):

Do you close your open applications often? If you tap twice on your home button so the last used apps bar on the bottom comes up there if you hold any of those icons for about 2 seconds pushed in, where after they will start to jiggle and you'll see an red close icon on the top left of those recently opend apps icons will show. Tap that! and the app will close and make space in memory. If opening up memory by hand doesn't work I'd suggest you check the connection of the button.

Comment: Apps are that are not active are dumped from memory immediately when necessary.

Comment: Not relevant to the problem.